# Difference between remote ssh and remote ssh nightly

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

There are two types of remote extensions as you see in the pictures. The ones in blue and the ones in green that are tagged with `nightly` at the end. They are both developed by microsoft and I can't see any difference between the two `Remote - SSH` extensions.

**What is their difference?**

[image]

Comment: I know nothing about vscode or your question, but a look at the Remote - SSH (Nightly) page (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-nightly) would seem to indicate that it is a newer version of the code but still in the testing phase. So they likely work on new features and release the latest version of the code each night. So, use the standard SSH one if you want stability and something known to work well. Use the nightly one if you want to use the latest features (but with chances of bugs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Remote - SSH` is the stable version and the `Remote - SSH (Nightly)` is the "nightly" build, meaning it contains the newest features that are not considered stable yet.

Actually, the build/release doesn't seem to be strictly nightly, but nightly is generally used to mean the *latest and greatest*.

[image: Snapshot of extension page]